# navigating a page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in page tem.jsp from there I made a call like this

`<a href="submit.htl" target="_parent">image.gif</a>`  this will load a submit.jsp page

on clicking a button i want to go back to temp.jsp.

since i opened with target attribute i can't close with the javascript `window.close()`, how can i close this page?

Comment: Can you post some code?  Hard to follow you question...

Comment: i want to close a page that is opened using target attribute in <a> tag

Comment: @True North Cretive : i opned a js page using a taget attribute in<a> tag. i want to close this page with any method(javascript). how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

You said "click a button to go back", why not make the "button" a link, just like the example of the link you used to get them to `submit.htl`?

```
<a href="temp.jsp" target="_parent">Go Back</a>
```